# How to add variables on each radio button?

Tags: c#, variables

Lets say I have for each radio button different variables. How can I do that? I searched the internet but haven't found nothing.

radioButton1

```
int a = 1
int b = 2
int c = 3
```

radioButton2

```
int a = 5
int b = 4
int c = 2
```

Comment: Create a class or structure, or a Tuple and store it in the Tag of the RadioButton.

Answer (score 0):

its unclear what your asking but I assume you want to change the value of the ints depending on what radio button is checked.

```
int a, b, c;
if (radioButton1.Checked)
{
    a = 1, b = 2, c = 3;
}
else
{
    a = 5, b = 4, c = 2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a user Control and add those Vars as a properties in a class

```
public class {

prop1 int var1
{
set, get
}
prop2 int var2
{
set, get
}
prop3 int var3
{
set, get
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like TaW said: You can extend your Button class and add the variables to it. Not really sure about the syntax but it should be something like this, where `RadioButton` is the class you want to extend and `MyButton` will be your custom class.

```
public class MyButton : RadioButton
{

    public int a;
    public int b;
    public int c;
}
```

All the methods and properties of `RadioButton` will also be available to your new class. And you can extend it with methods to read and write your additional properties `a`, `b` and `c`.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int a, b, c;
            if (radioButton1.Checked == true)
            {
                a = 1; b = 2; c = 3;
            }
            if (radioButton2.Checked == true)
            {
                a = 5; b = 4; c = 2;

            }
        }
```

As well as you can use same thing for radioButton1_CheckedChanged event,it will be depended on your requirement :) Good luck!